# Transferring music from computer

Tags: sync

Why does my Android phone show up on the Widows Media Player Sync function as a Linux O.S? Transferred music files from the computer show up on the Android phone music app but will not play.

Comment: That's because Android uses the Linux kernel, so it is a Linux based OS. Probably you're device's music player does not support the music format you are using, hence it doesn't play.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Android is based on Linux. Android uses Linux as part of it core operating system. This does not mean that you can run Linux programs on Android nor can you run android apps on Linux.